# spellchecker plugin gives me Error: Missing input parameter 'text'

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to use TinyMCE's PHP Spellchecker 4.0 plugin but keep getting a `Error: Missing input parameter 'text'` error when I try to have it do any actual spell checking.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    menubar:false,
    statusbar:false,
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: ["link","spellchecker"],
    toolbar: "bold italic | numlist bullist | link unlink | spellchecker",
    force_br_newlines: true,
    force_p_newlines: false,
    forced_root_block: '',
    height: 300,
    spellchecker_rpc_url: "spellchecker.php"
 });
</script>
<textarea>tgis is misspelled text</textarea>
```

You can test it out live here:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/tinymce/test.html

Here's a link to the version of the spellchecking program I'm using:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/PHP_Spellchecker

I used Wireshark to see what the above is sending over and it's this (via POST):

```
{"id":"c0","method":"spellcheck","params":{"lang":"en","words":["tgis","is","misspelled","text"]}}
```

And the response I'm getting:

```
{"error":"Missing input parameter 'text'."}
```

The response is correct - there is no input parameter named text. But I'd expect the javascript to add it if it was needed.

I tried doing `<textarea name="text">` and `<textarea id="text">` as well to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is broken. As per my OP what it's posting is json encoded. And yet the PHP engine is expecting non-JSON encoded code. From `spellchecker\includes\Engine.php`:

```
    $method = self::getParam("method", "spellcheck");
    $lang = self::getParam("lang", "en_US");
    $text = self::getParam("text");
```

Replacing that with this got it working for me:

```
    global $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
    $data = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
    $method = $data->method;
    $lang = $data->params->lang;
    $text = $data->params->words;
```

I think it's dumb that the plugin listed pretty prominently on their website doesn't work out of the box but whatever.

Comment: I submitted a bug report: http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=6925